# invalid_grant error using omniauth-reddit in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, omniauth

I'm trying to use the omniauth-reddit gem. I have gotten as far as getting the account holder to say they want to "allow" my app to grant access to their account. After I click allow, I get an error from Rails:

```
OAuth2::Error
invalid_grant: {"error": "invalid_grant"}
```

This is what my omniauth.rb file looks like:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :reddit, "XXX", "YYY", {:duration => "permanent", :scope => "identity,subscribe,vote,submit,history,read,mysubreddits"}
end
```

And my routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'homes#index'

  get '/auth/reddit', as: :reddit_login
  get '/auth/reddit/callback', to: "sessions#create"
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having this too. Seems like the strategy for omniauth-reddit isn't working correctly.

EDIT: Looks like the issue comes from a newer version of the omniauth-oatuh2 gem.

If you include `gem 'omniauth-oauth2', '~> 1.3.1'` in your Gemfile, it should work.